# Is it possible with upload a file AND submit text in a single form?

Tags: php, sql, database, forms, upload

I'm writing a plugin for wordpress where certain information like a name and e-mailaddress and some info is stored in an SQL database table. I've got that working perfectly. But this information also needs a picture to go with it.

So when wordpress admin fills in the form, has the file selected and clicks submit I want the file to be uploaded into a directory and its location stored in a database along with the name and e-mailaddress.

All this preferably needs to be done in just one form.

Is this possible? Or is there another way that would make the end user click only once on a sumbit button.

Comment: If all the fields are inside the same `<form>` they are submitted together.

Comment: Does that also count for uploading a file? Because I read that you need to set an enctype for that. Which I tried, but then the text input doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just make sure you set the form `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and that you use `type="file"` for file input and regular inputs (`type="text"`, etc) for texts.

You'll need to write a code to move uploaded files to a location you want, as well as to add its info to the database.

See these two nice tutorials: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) and [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it should be possible.

Just ensure that your `<form>` has the attributes `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `method="post"`

By PHP side after submit, you can use `$_POST` variables as usual, plus `$_FILES` for handling uploads with `<input type="file">` in the same form.

See [this PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for details on file upload.